# Can startActivityForResult be used as a security measure to identify the calling component

Tags: android, security

If we have an Android activity X that is being called by other components. We want to ensure that only legitimate calls are made. Is it OK to make the calling components start our activity with the [Activity.startActivityForResult()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult%28android.content.Intent,%20int%29) method which will allow X to check the caller against a predefined white list? As [documented](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#getCallingActivity%28%29) the standard startActivity() method will not inform the called activity about the identity of the caller.

The documentation of the startActivityForResult method states:

> Note that this method should only be used with Intent protocols that
>   are defined to return a result

Still if the caller just ignores the result, then what would be the damage?

This of course should come as an extra security measure on top of having  X protected with a permission.

Why?

Defining a permission is a technical solution for this classical issue - limit the access to an exposed component. However potential malicious apps could just request this permission and hope that the user does not pay attention during the installation. The latter can and WILL happen or at least there are no technical means to prevent it.

A signature level permission can be defined which will solve the issue. Still this puts the restriction of having all the callers being signed with the same key, which is not always possible.

Another approach is using signed/encrypted extras and checking the signature. However then we get the issue how to store and protect the keys used for this. The private/secret key has to be in the app and has to stay unchanged which means that eventually it could get stolen. Keychain storage offers some protection and still apps can request key access and it is up to the user to decide whether to grant it or not.

Thank you

Vasil

P.S.
I know that I'm trying to find a technical solution for the "careless user" problem which is generally hard.

Answer (score 1):

Well to me it seems that you just want to check whether or not your Activity can be ran by another application. I'm also assuming you do want certain applications to run your Activity and that there will not be a result to the calling activity.

If it were up to me I would just require the calling activity to call startActivityForResult, thus including the  package and activity information in the Intent. I could then get these during the onCreate method of my Activity with the respective getter functions and compare them to  the whitelist, and choose whether or not to finish my activity then and there. If the caller uses only startActivity, then these fields will be null anyway and fail the check.

Not sure if that's the most elegant way but it seems most simple to me.

Answer (score -1):

One way to accomplish this is to have the calling activity pass in a predetermined value into the intent used to start it. Then the calling activities can put that value into the intent used to start your activity. Then in your activity you can call `getIntent()` and check to make sure that the predetermined value is in there before doing anything.

Comment: As far as I understand your suggestion is to send a predetermined extra and check for it in the receiver.
This would not prevent a potential hacker from determining the exact string and program a malware to send it. Then I would not be able to distinguish between legitimate and illegal calls.

Comment: This suggestion affords no protection at all